# How to override/wrap a single function in a third-party class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

The situation is as follows, I have a third party interface defined as an abstract class in their public code. Internally, there is a private class that acts as the implementation.

My code is passed an instance of this private implementation, and I want to overwrite/wrap a specific method in this implementation, whats the best way to do this?

```
def PublicClass():
   def method_to_overwrite(self, par1, par2):
       raise NotImplementedError()

   def other_method1(self):
       raise NotImplementedError()
 
   ...

def _PrivateImpl(PublicClass):
   ...
```

My code:

```
def function_called_by_third_party(..., private_class_instance):
    # Want to update public_class_instance.method_to_overwrite before calling inner function
    inner_function(..., public_class_instance)
```

Comment: `def PublicClass()` - that is a function definition not a class definition. Did you mean `class PublicClass:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a function of your own design to the method of the class of the instance.  All future instances will *use* the new function.

```
class PublicClass:
   def method_to_overwrite(self, par1, par2):
       raise NotImplementedError()

   def other_method1(self):
       raise NotImplementedError()

class _PrivateImpl(PublicClass):
    pass

def f(self,par1,par2):
    return f'foo-{par1}-{par2}'

q = _PrivateImpl()

q.__class__.method_to_overwrite = f

r = _PrivateImpl()
```

---

```
>>>
>>> q.method_to_overwrite('w','x')
'foo-w-x'
>>> r.method_to_overwrite('v','b')
'foo-v-b'
>>>
```

---

> whats the best way to do this?

I have no Idea if this is the best way.